Mapping the right touchpad key for working as a left touchpad key by AutoHotKey
I'm trying to make my windows notebook touchpad working as on Mac. I want both side clicks works as left-click with one finger and right-click with two fingers.
Windows has an option "Tap with two fingers to right-click" in Touchpad settings, and that I actually need. But it works only on the left half of the touchpad, because the right half has the native right click. So I'm trying to map the right button to the left button, and hope that this windows feature will work on top of that.
I use AutoHotKey v2 with the script "RButton::LButton". It works as is says, but unfortunately it disables the windows feature for mapping two-fingers to right-click.
Any idea how to solve it? Is it possible to implement two-fingers mapping by AutoHotKey as well?
